# Any potential issues in developing/testing app with in-app purchase intended for a client?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

We have developed an app for a client which we deliver to them as an ipa signed with our dev credentials and bundle identifier etc. 
When they receive it they strip off the existing credentials and re-sign it and submit it themselves to the app store.

Now there is to going to be a new version of the app that will include in-app purchase. In order to develop and test it I'm going to have to set up an entry for our in-house version of app in iTunes connect in order to create some products.

I've never done in-app purchase or set up an iTunes connect account before so was wondering if there are any potential issues I need to be aware of bearing in mind what I've said about how the app is delivered to the client and submitted to the app store.

For example:
- can I easily set up an iTunes connect account for an app that will never be released, for example I see there's a paid applications contract to agree to? (I say the app will never be released - what I mean is the exact version we deliver to the client will never be released in that form, its bundle identifier will be altered and thus will be different).

- the product identifiers used during the development phase will be different than the eventual product identifiers. I already have a .plist config file in use, are there any potential issue with adding the product identifier names in there, and when the client re-signs the app they edit it to contain the actual product identifier names?
- I thought I remember reading somewhere (but not can't find it) that after creating an entry for an app on iTunes connect there's a time window within which the app must be submitted. If this is correct then would the iTunes connect account disappear? If this happened before finishing the app I'd have to go through the hassle of creating a new bundle id and associated profiles and create a new iTunes connect entry to compete it?

If you have any issues I need to be aware of I'd be keen to hear.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plan seems to be fine, however be careful when shifting things to the product, as there are so many parts to this operation(bundle identifiers, etc...). A small mistake could set you back weeks if not months.

Comment: How can a test product be created? If I create a temporary app on iTunes connect then add a product it says it needs to be submitted for review. Is there a way of just creating a product without it having to be submitted for review?

Answer (score 0):

We have apps with IAP that we develop for other clients and they submit with their own credentials.  We also have our own app on the app store with IAP.  We just have to make sure that our clients set up their IAP with the same ids as we set them up with.  Other than that we have not had any problems with it.  Also, we fully do IAP fulfillment (downloads and IAP store display) from our servers and not from the clients.